# GitKraken is not ignoring cache files in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitkraken

The following is a snippet from my local .gitignore file:

```
# files ending in .cache can be ignored
*.[Cc]ache
# but keep track of directories ending in .cache
!*.[Cc]ache/
```

Despite this, GitKraken detects hundreds of StyleCop cache files of the form:

```
a/b/c.d/StyleCop.Cache
```

as unstaged, new files in my project directory. Other Git tools like Git Bash and Visual Studio's built-in Git support are correctly ignoring the cache files and not ignoring directories that end in .Cache.

I've tried adding the line:

```
*.Cache
```

to the projects .git/info/exclude file and even added a global ignore file that my .gitconfig points to using the key core.excludesfile with the exclusion, but GitKraken still detects the StyleCop cache files. If I add the *.Cache pattern to the end of my local .gitignore file, then GitKraken ignores the files, but I am not in charge of the contents of the .gitignore file for this project and would need to make an argument for modifying it for a specific tool that only I am using.

How can I get GitKraken to ignore the .Cache files without modifying my local .gitignore file?

Comment: Seems to be you used the [Ignore Visual Studio temporary files suggested .gitignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exchanging some emails with Axosoft, I have a partial solution to the problem. Changing the exclusion pattern `!*.[Cc]ache/` to `!*.[Cc]ache/**` appears to resolve the issue without adding special patterns for StyleCop to the .gitignore file, and without changing the behavior of other git tools.

It appears that the .gitignore file takes precedence over the `.git/info/exclude` file and global `core.excludesfile` option, so as long as the repository's .gitignore has the exclusion pattern, there isn't a way to override it, and the .gitignore must be modified.

Comment: Saving `.gitignore` with this change updated `GitKraken` unstaged files immediately. Thanks for your research.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make these changes for GitKraken to understand my exclusions.

Broken in GitKraken (works elsewhere):

```
UWP/**/*

!UWP/MyApp/
!UWP/MyApp/*/

!UWP/MyApp/Assets/*
!UWP/MyApp/Package.appxmanifest
```

Fixed, works everywhere:

```
UWP/**
UWP/MyApp/**

!UWP/MyApp/Assets/*
!UWP/MyApp/Package.appxmanifest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting those files from your repository and look at your unstaged files inside of gitkraken. Sometimes they need to be 'reset' before the gitignore goes into effect.

Alternatively inside of gitkraken, on the far right window with the "unstaged files", you can right click the files you want to ignore and select `ignore -> all files with extension .Cache`

Comment: I'm afraid that deleting the files, starting GitKraken, then regenerating them (via build process) did not help. GitKraken detected them and failed to ignore them. As for the ignore option in the context menu, unfortunately what this does is add a line to the local .gitignore file, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: can you explain why you don't want to add a line to the .gitignore file?

Comment: I understand you aren't in charge of the .gitignore file, however, what is there reasoning to keeping the files if, in your case, you'd much rather remove them?

Comment: The main reason I'd like to avoid adding the line is that it seems to me that GitKraken is misbehaving here - other git tools are interpreting the .gitignore file (correctly?) in such a way that the cache files are ignored just using the current contents of the .gitignore file. The fact that I would have to present a case for changing the .gitignore file to accommodate GitKraken adds to this. As for keeping the files - I don't want to remove them. They are necessary and useful, but shouldn't be seen by GitKraken as unstaged, new files.

Comment: Well if the files are modified by a build process and are included of your repository, why would they ever not be staged? I would be more upset if GitKraken hid files that would be updated to the repository on my next push.

Comment: Sorry, I am being unclear I think. The files in question are not part of the repository - they are temporary, local cache files for an extension our team uses called StyleCop. They are regenerated for each individual upon building our solution so as to make the extension work more quickly, but they are not actually a part of our solution/repository. Much like the stuff in Visual Studio's obj/ directory (intermediate output objects), they are generated for each build but not part of the final product and should be ignored by git.